# Caching in Docker with only PHP

Tags: php, docker, caching

I have a Docker container `php:8.2.1-cli`. The problem is, **nothing** is cached on my website, *not fonts, not images, not images*. My website loads extremely slow. Each time I reload the website, all this things are loaded again (Chrome network inspector).

I tried to use "**meta cache tag**", php-**gzip** and **opcache**. The problem is, images, fonts and style cannot be cached such way (I suppose).

I don't have much experience with Docker, so I don't know, do I use nginx or apache? If no, how does my website work?

I have read, that nginx and apache provide build-in support for caching, but is it possible for me to enable that? My phpinfo tells me "**Server API - Built-in HTTP server**"..

I really have no idea how can I properly configure my Docker/PHP/server/website to enable image/svg/css/font caching...

Comment: The reason why your site is slow is not because you're missing HTTP caching which, as an aside, doesn't make sense to run on the same box that is serving that content. It's because you're trying to run your website using PHP's built-in _testing_ webserver, which can handle exactly _one_ HTTP connection at a time, so it's impossible to serve anything in parallel. Nginx and Apache, by default, will provide the ability to serve _many_ requests in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch to the php-apache image or the php-fpm image with nginx.

Both are good.

Comment: Oh, so this cli is not suitable at all? Do I need to rebuild the whole system?

Comment: If you are developing a CLI program, PHP-CLI is great. But, if you are developing a website, you need to use php-apache (mod_php) or php-fpm + nginx. The PHP built-in server should not be used for anything beyond some local dev testing or learning. You don't need to rebuild the whole system. Just switch your docker image and go from there.